# Migrating questions from Skeptic Exchange

Tags: discussion, questions, migration

This proposal was created as an SEv2 of http://www.skepticexchange.org

Can we/should we/how do we migrate content over to skeptics.SE.

Comment: Wasn't there some incompatibility of licenses?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Taking a quick look, www.skepticexchange.org is CC BY-NC-SA, while this site is CC BY-SA (designation for Creative Commons licenses).  Therefore, the only people who could move questions and answers would be the copyright holders or licensees, since moving them would remove the non-commercial attribution.

Therefore, we legally can't do it en masse.